# Getting image from Google Drive link in PHP

Tags: php, image, google-drive-api

I want to extract image from following google drive url in php, for that first i need to get the html part then get img src and then get the actual image. But somehow iam not able to get the html part . I have tried both **file_get_contents** and **curl** request.

url - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz14TICwUk77V25VQzd1MF8wLTQ/edit?pli=1

**Here is my curl script**

```
<?php
$url = "http://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz14TICwUk77V25VQzd1MF8wLTQ/edit?pli=1";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);      
print_r($output);
```

**Output**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Permanently</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Permanently</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz14TICwUk77V25VQzd1MF8wLTQ/edit?pli=1">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Here is my php script using file_get_contents**

```
<?php

$url = "http://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz14TICwUk77V25VQzd1MF8wLTQ/edit?pli=1";

$html= file_get_contents($url);

print_r($html);
```

Output

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz14TICwUk77V25VQzd1MF8wLTQ/edit?pli=1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory on line 5
```

and my **allow_url_fopen** is true in php.ini

any help is appreciated.

Comment: have a look at: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php

Comment: In particular https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get and https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

Comment: Your http request is redirected to https. Use https and there won`t be a redirect.

Comment: @SandeepKumarSingh You are welcome. Did`t expected to solve the whole problem. So I made the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTTP request is redirected to HTTPS. Use HTTPS and there won’t be a redirect.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of curl use simplehtmldom for scraping data from google drive

Here are good articles: [Link 1](http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications) & [Link 2](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library--net-11856)